# Pagination using Querymore

Tags: visualforce

How to do pagination in salesforce using Querymore.
In OrderItem object StandardSetController is not available and pagination using OFFSET returns only 2k records.
So I'm thinking about doing this using Querymore method.
If any other way is also possible than please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need pagination by any arbitrarily sortable field? Or are you okay with using only Id (created order) for sorting?

Comment: Yes I want pagination by Arbitrarily sortable field. but Id will also work.